# Hi! am trying to make a conversational bot in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

```
import os,time
import random
import sys

namea = ['what is your name','whats your name','what is your name?','whats your name?']
greeta = ['hello','hi','hi there','hello there']
birth = ['what is your date of birth','what is your date of birth?','what is your DOB','what is your DOB?']
botmaster = ['who is your botmaster','who is your botmaster?','who is your father','who is your mother']
greetb = ['hi there','hello','hi my name is Ananymous','hello there']
nameb = ['I am called Ananymous','my name is Ananymous','I am called Ananymous']

K = '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n Ananymous \n\n onnline...........'
print(K)
while True:
    C = raw_input('$').strip()
    Cbot =C.bot()

    if C == '':
            print '$ Bye'
            time.sleep(1)
            os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
            break
    elif Cbot in namea:
            print '$' + (random.choice(nameb))
    elif Cbot in greeta:
            print '$' + (random.choice(greetb))
    elif Cbot in botmaster:
            print [('$ My botmaster Kumar')]
    elif Cbot in birth:
            print [('$ My Birthdate Is May 8 2017')]
    C.bot()
```

This is my coding it throws an error like :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ananymous.py", line 16, in <module>
    Cbot =C.bot()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'bot'
```

Comment: The error message says it all: you cannot apply the unknown `bot` method on a string (i.e. on `C`). Which bot API do you intend to use? There is nothing imported for that in your code?

Comment: yeah trincot, i got a clear view ... thanks for your answer..